# react component order for fetching data

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react so maybe this is simple question.

I have two components that are calling database - CallsCharts and CallsList. I want to first render CallsCharts and when it finish I want to query database for CallsList. How can I do that? When I leave it like this, CallsList is always first to load.

Can I somehow choose priority?

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid">
            <CallsCharts/>
            <CallsList/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You can compose them. `CallsList` can be a child of `CallsCharts`. In this way, `CallsCharts` will only render `CallsList` when `CallsCharts` has finished querying api.

Comment: yes , you can you need to call both database call and stores the value in state and check if state .data.lengh>0 then and only then you need  to render the component otherwise not

Comment: If you are using api layer, why not to fetch both call-lists and call-charts data in one request?

Comment: Because fetching data from database is slow so I divide it to two different query...

Answer (score 0):

You can compose them. CallsList can be a child of CallsCharts. In this way, CallsCharts will only render CallsList when CallsCharts has finished querying api.

As simple as:

```
class CallsCharts extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    // fetch charts
  }

  render() {
   const { charts } = this.props;

   if (checkChart(charts)) {
     return <CallsList />
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see! And even fetch part will be called onyl when the first one will return data?

    `const response = await fetch('/api/getCallData');

     const response2 = await fetch('/api/getCallData2');
    `

Answer (score 0):

Compose your components and implement them as function component. this way you can return a promise and wait for the resolve in your child component.

```
render() {
  return (
  <div className="container-fluid">
    <CallsCharts>
      {({promise}) => <CallsList promise={promise}/>}
    </CallsCharts>
  </div>
);
}
```